# Error Compiling `spacy` Package with Pip and Requirements.txt (Mac M1)

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, pipenv

I'm trying to install the `spacy` package and its dependencies using `pip` and a `requirements.txt` file in a Python environment. However, I'm encountering the following error during the installation process:

### requirements.txt

```
-i https://pypi.python.org/simple
anyio==3.7.0
appdirs==1.4.4
...
spacy==3.0.3
spacy-legacy==3.0.1
spacy-lookups-data==1.0.3
...
websockets==11.0.3
wrapt==1.15.0; python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4'
xmltodict==0.13.0; python_version >= '3.4'
zipp==3.16.2; python_version >= '3.8'
```

I run the command `pip install -r requirements.txt`, also tried `conda install --file requirements.txt`

### Error

```
      Compiling spacy/tokens/morphanalysis.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/tokens/_retokenize.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/matcher/matcher.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/matcher/phrasematcher.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/matcher/dependencymatcher.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/symbols.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/vectors.pyx because it changed.
      [ 1/41] Cythonizing spacy/attrs.pyx
      [ 2/41] Cythonizing spacy/kb.pyx
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File ".../site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File ".../site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File ".../site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 225, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 211, in setup_package
        File ".../site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1154, in cythonize
          cythonize_one(*args)
        File ".../site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1321, in cythonize_one
          raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
      Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: spacy/kb.pyx
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I'm using Python 3.9.16 on macOS (M1). I've tried updating Pipenv, ensuring the correct dependencies are installed, and recreating the virtual environment, but I'm still encountering this issue. How can I resolve this error and successfully install the `spacy` package with its dependencies?

Any help or guidance would be awsome. TY!

Comment: Please be aware that all Conda Forge packages are precompiled, including `spacy`, which is available for **osx-arm64**. I.e., `conda create -n spacy_env -c conda-forge python=3.9 spacy` works just fine for all.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying this one